# One user and one guest in Office 365 but Sharepoint lists 6 users

Tags: security, data

A client of mine subscribes Office 365. He  is the only full user, and there is only one guest user that has access to some shared folders in One Drive. However, when he goes to SharePoint>Manage Users, there are 6 Sharepoint users, but they do not appear in the list of users. Microsoft support says they are shadow profiles. My client  is worried if thoe shadow profiles represent any risk to data security, breach, hack or other unauthorized access to his company's files and information. His company is small but has contracts with one or other corporation with strict NDA signed. He must ensure that he is in compliance. Does anyone had any experience with those shadow profiles and do they represent a data security risk?

Answer (score 0):

All users must authenticate via Azure Active Directory, to access SharePoint Online. As long as those user accounts do not exist in Azure Active Directory, this does not pose a risk (they cannot login, because they don't have an AD user account).